# How do I get the count number of weekdays in a datetime column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-timestamp

I have a timestamp in `mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss` format from January to March. How do I count "how many days are Monday" in the range of A1:A199? (Or How Many are Tuesday, Wednesday, Saturday?

This gives me a value of `5`

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTUNIQUE(TEXT(A2:A199,"ddd")))
```

I need to know how many Mondays from Jan to Mar and by manually calculating there are 7 Mondays in my data (A1:A199) and 8 Thursdays and 9 Saturdays.

Comment: please read: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(A2:A, TEXT(A2:A, "ddd")="Mon"))))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

- if you need all days:

  ```
  =QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), TEXT(A2:A, "dddd"),)),
   "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1<>'' group by Col1 label count(Col1)''")
  ```

  [image: 0]

---

- if you need all days from a certain time period:

  ```
  =QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(TEXT(A2:A, "dddd"),
   A2:A>=DATE(2019,4,1),
   A2:A<=DATE(2019,4,22))),
   "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1<>'' group by Col1 label count(Col1)''")
  ```

  [image: 0]

---

- if you need all unique days per week:

  ```
  =QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(UNIQUE(IF(LEN(A2:A),
   DATE(20&MID(A2:A, 7, 2), LEFT(A2:A, 2), MID(A2:A, 4, 2)), )),
   "dd/mm/yyyy"), "30/12/1899",""), "dddd")),
   "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1<>'' group by Col1 label count(Col1)''")
  ```

[image]

---

- locale fix:

  ```
  =QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(UNIQUE(IF(LEN(A2:A); 
   DATE(20&MID(A2:A; 7; 2); LEFT(A2:A; 2); MID(A2:A; 4; 2)); )); "mm/dd/yyyy"); 
   "12/30/1899";""); "dddd")); 
   "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1<>'' group by Col1 label count(Col1)''")
  ```

Comment: This did not work as expected. I need unique Monday count so for example, these 3 rows should count as one(1) Monday since the time is different but the day is same. 03/25/19 11:58:15
03/25/19 11:30:56
03/25/19 10:40:14 ...  I know by manually reading and counting all 199 rows (and growing by 4 or 10 rows each unique day) that I currently have ... 7 Mondays in my data (A1:A199) and 8 Thursdays and 9 Saturdays.

Comment: 03/30/19 13:08:07 Saturday
03/30/19 12:59:13 Saturday
03/30/19 10:30:02 Saturday
03/30/19 10:28:28 Saturday
03/28/19 16:59:49 Thursday
03/28/19 13:07:02 Thursday
03/28/19 12:40:47 Thursday
03/28/19 11:09:00 Thursday
03/25/19 15:58:33 Monday
03/25/19 11:58:15 Monday
03/25/19 11:30:56 Monday
03/25/19 10:40:14 Monday
03/23/19 14:07:10 Saturday
03/23/19 12:56:01 Saturday
03/23/19 11:52:41 Saturday
03/23/19 11:34:13 Saturday
03/23/19 10:31:10 Saturday
03/21/19 14:23:38 Thursday

Comment: Don't know how to format that but it has 18 rows from 3/21 to 3/30

Comment: 2 Saturdays, 2 Thursdays and 1 Monday

Comment: Can't get it to work as it inserts bunch of rows with dates and then claims only 1 Saturday and 1 Sunday and I have 9 Saturdays and no Sundays. All the days show up at bottom of the list and for the first 20 or so rows, the dates don't match the data in A2:A199 ... will keep playing with it

Comment: Added to row 23 forward and also image of what happens

Comment: @rosa try this pls: `=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(UNIQUE(IF(LEN(A2:A);
 DATE(20&MID(A2:A; 7; 2); LEFT(A2:A; 2); MID(A2:A; 4; 2)); ));
 "mm/dd/yyyy"); "12/30/1899";""); "dddd"));
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1<>'' group by Col1 label count(Col1)''")`

Comment: One last question: If Col4 contains a numeric value (ie. 111, 123.00, 99.00), how could this be included in the following: "select Col1,Col4,count(Col1),sum(Col4) where Col1<>'' group by Col1,Col4 label count(Col1),sum(Col4)''"

Comment: that wont do. show me here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wXTvS32sIKymS3rZkOIhLt1vfPLNUF2PWn4CHhsYeHk/edit#gid=1008970455

Comment: Copied 2 columns (originally Col1 and Col4 in sheet)

Comment: Sum(Col2) for Monday, Tuesday.... Saturday just like the original which counted how many Monday, Tuesday.... Saturday so it should end up with 4 days,4 rows with 3 columns ... the Col2 is Col4 in the original sheet

Comment: try like this: `={QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(UNIQUE(IF(LEN(A2:A),
 DATE(20&MID(A2:A, 7, 2), LEFT(A2:A, 2), MID(A2:A, 4, 2)), )),
 "mm/dd/yyyy"), "12/30/1899",""), "dddd")),
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1<>'' group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"),
 QUERY(QUERY({ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A),
 TEXT(DATE(IF(LEN(A2:A),20,)&MID(A2:A,7,2),LEFT(A2:A,2),MID(A2:A,4,2)),"dddd"),)),B2:B},
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"),"select Col2 where Col1 is not null")}`